# Oozie - PigStorage - Scheme not present in uri

Tags: apache-pig, oozie

When i run my pig script locally (pig -file script.pig -param INPUT=val -param OUTPUT=val) everything is working fine. But when I schedule my pig script using Oozie (Coordinator/Workflow) then script fails. I dont understand why...

Can someone help me out?

**Pig script**

```
alarms = LOAD '$INPUT' USING PigStorage('|', '-noschema') AS (
    row_num:long,
    timestamp:chararray,
    protocol_name:chararray,   
    source_ip:chararray,
    destination_ip:chararray,
    source_port:int,
    destination_port:int
);

alarms_projection = FOREACH alarms {
    GENERATE
    SUBSTRING(timestamp, 0, 10) as alarm_date:chararray,
    SUBSTRING(timestamp, 11, 19) as alarm_time:chararray,
    protocol_name,
    source_ip,
    destination_ip,
    source_port,
    destination_port;
}

STORE alarms_projection INTO '$OUTPUT' USING PigStorage('|');
```

**ERROR**

```
Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.PigMain], exception invoking main(), Scheme not present in uri /etl/av/complete/alarms
org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherException: Scheme not present in uri /etl/av/complete/alarms
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMapper.map(LauncherMapper.java:177)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:430)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:342)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1594)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:163)
Caused by: org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherException: Scheme not present in uri /etl/av/complete/alarms
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherURIHandlerFactory.getURIHandler(LauncherURIHandlerFactory.java:41)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.PrepareActionsDriver.doOperations(PrepareActionsDriver.java:65)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMapper.executePrepare(LauncherMapper.java:444)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMapper.map(LauncherMapper.java:173)
    ... 8 more

Oozie Launcher failed, finishing Hadoop job gracefully
```

Comment: you might want to post the code of your pig action

Answer (score 0):

It was a configuration error in the workflow.xml. I was using a prepare statement to empty the output directory. But instead of setting the path hdfs://node:port/path/to/the/file I used /path/to/the/files.

The right way of using prepare

```
        <prepare>
            <delete path="hdfs://node:8020/path/to/files"/>
        </prepare>
```